# Question about higher order mean field equation $\left(-\Delta_{g}\right)^{m} u+\lambda=\lambda \frac{e^{2 m u}}{\int_{M} e^{2 m u} d \mu_{g}}$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde

I'm reading Dr.Luca Martinazzi's paper
[Existence of solutions to a higher dimensional
mean-field equation on manifolds](https://arxiv.org/abs/1001.5231)
which proves that for $m \geq 1$, there is an existence result for the equation
$$
\left(-\Delta_{g}\right)^{m} u+\lambda=\lambda \frac{e^{2 m u}}{\int_{M} e^{2 m u} d \mu_{g}}
$$
on a closed Riemannian manifold $(M, g)$ of dimension $2 m$ for certain values of $\lambda$.

This is a little strange for me, when dimension becomes higher, we need the $m$'s power of $\Delta$:$\left(-\Delta_{g}\right)^{m} $  to obtain the existence of the solution.

What happens when we just consider the equation
$$
-\Delta_{g} u+\lambda=\lambda \frac{e^{2  u}}{\int_{M} e^{2  u} d \mu_{g}}
$$
on higher dimension manifold?

I read the proof and it is the Adams-Moser-Trudinger inequality part which require the $m$ 's power of $\Delta$. I'm curious what about the equation when $m=1$ but on a high dimension manifold?